# Laravel-mix, Javascript and scope

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a problem with accessing a function in javascript on laravel framework. I have a file called pile.js and in that file i have a function that looks like this:

```
    function initPile(json) {
       ...
    }
```

It is "compiled" using laravel-mix and placed in my public/js folder and included with this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/pile.js') }}" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

but when i try to use the function from the file like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" defer>

            initPile('@json($data)');

         </script>
```

i get the error: ReferenceError: initPile is not defined

i tried google this error and all the results says im to assign it to a global variable using

```
window.initPile = function(json) { ... }
```

and then calling it like this

```
window.initPile('@json($data)');
```

but that only results in the same error.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the solution was to assign it to window but because i hade defer in both my script tags the function was called before being declared.

Comment: you should post the fix